Neovim: Close file/buffer/whatever it is, but don't let it come back via :n or :N
First, sorry for my lack of knowledge of all the terminology; I've used Neovim for a while, and vi/Vim for a long time before that, but I've never really used them much for more than simple "insert", "replace", "copy", "cut", "paste" and such, on a single file per invocation of the program. So, I don't really know the difference between "buffers" and "files" and "windows" and whatnot. I apologize for any lack of clarity or precision that that may cause in my question, but please keep it in mind whenever I say something like "file".
Anyway, I am finally trying to branch out into using other features too, and I'm having a problem with editing:
I've discovered :n and :N to move through the open files. That's great, but if I have a bunch of open files, when I am done with one, I want it to be gone (I mean from my Neovim session; I don't mean I want the actual file system file deleted). Trying to figure out how to do this, I found :bd, which at first seemed to do what I was hoping. But I then used :n and/or :N, and to my surprise the file that I thought I had just closed came back.
Poking around some more, I saw that :help :bd says something about the buffer not actually being completely deleted. I don't really understand what it's saying there, but it seemed likely that it had to do with issue that I'm having.
So I looked around some more, and saw a suggestion on the internet, which seemed like it might be related, to use :bw instead of :bd. I then read :help :bw, and again although I don't grok the details, it got my hopes up: "Like :bdelete, but really delete the buffer. It also says "Don't use this unless you know what you are doing", which I most assuredly do not, but that's not gonna stop me. Unfortunately, it seems to have the same behavior as :bd (with respect to what I'm hoping for).
I also tried a shot-in-the-dark :close, but that seemed to behave the same way.
Is there a way to do what I want? Get rid of a file from an editing session, and not have it mysteriously reappear when I do something like :n/:N? I just want something that will cause Neovim to behave like, say, a web browser would if I did a File/Close Tab: That particular file is gone from my editing session, and won't come back unless I explicitly ask for it back.
To be clear, I understand that (from the point of view of someone more familiar with Neovim) I apparently did ask for it back (via :n/:N), so if the problem is something "You're misunderstanding how to switch between files" rather than "You're misunderstanding how to close files", that's fine - I'd like to learn of a way to accomplish what I want regardless of precisely what it is that I'm doing wrong in my current attempts.

I would use :bn and :bN to navigate through the buffers (files) and use :bd to remove the current buffer (file) from the list.
My understanding of :n and :N is that they loop through the files of the arglist (by default the list of files present in the command line).
If you want to stick with that list you could:

Remove the current buffer from the arglist with:

:argdelete


Drop the current buffer from the viewport with:

:bdelete

Remark: you can inspect the arglist using the :args Vim command.

Learn to use Vim's :help.
All of your problems can be solved by reading the documentation.
Unclear about terminology? Read :help buffers or :help windows (they point to the same entry).
You'll find the following two lines there which explain the differences between buffers, files and windows wonderfully:

A buffer is the in-memory text of a file.
A window is a viewport on a buffer.

Now let's apply this to your problem with :n/:N.
What does that command do?
Let's ask :help :n.
It's not very telling in itself, so let's scroll up to get some context.
Turns out :help :n is in a section called The Argument List.
That's news to us. Reading the introductory paragraph, we learn that it contains all the file names you passed to Vim.
We can follow that all and any command related to buffers does nothing to alter the argument list.
To remove a file from the argument list, use :argdelete {pattern}
A little example, we start Vim with three file names:
vim first second third

Now let's have a look at the buffer and arg lists with :ls and :args respectively and we'll find all three files there:
:ls
  1 %a=  "first"                        line 1
  2      "second"                       line 0
  3      "third"                        line 0

:args
[first] second  third

Now let's :bufwipe 2 and in fact, it's gone from the buflist but not from the arglist:
:ls
  1 %a=  "first"                        line 1
  3      "third"                        line 0

:args
[first] second  third

Now calling :n advances to the second item of the arglist, a file called second.
Opening a file will create a buffer for it.
:ls
  1 # =  "first"                        line 1
  3      "third"                        line 0
  4 %a   "second"                       line 1

:args
[first] second  third

Note that the newly created buffer for second got number 4.
Take a look at :help buffer-list which compares buffer list and arglist commands.
Either operate on the arglist with :n, :argdelete, etc. or on the buffer list with :bn, :bdelete, etc.
